# Show Widget in the Html

Tags: magento2, checkout, widget, knockout

I have an html file for checkout where I want to show the widget which is coming from the database . Instead of displaying the widget it shows widget code. I have attached screenshot of the same. Thank you for the help in advance.[image]

```
<div class="store-container-inner" data-bind="visible: canVisibleBlock(), variable: isVisibleStoreContainer">
<label class="pickup-store-label" ><span id="pickup-store" data-bind="i18n: 'Select Store'"></span></label>
<select name="pickup_store"
        class="required-entry"
        datascope="shippingAddress.pickup_store"
        data-validate="{required:true}"
        data-bind="
                  options: getStoreOption(),
                  optionsValue: 'value',
                  optionsText: 'label',
                  optionsCaption: $t('Select a Store To Pickup'),
                  value: storeOptionValue,
                  event: {change: changeStore(storeOptionValue)}">
</select><br>
<!-- ko if: isVisibleStoreInformation -->
<div id="show-address">
    <div class="shipping-information-content">
        <div class="store-name">
            <strong data-bind="i18n: 'Store Name'"></strong>
            <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().name"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="store-address">
            <strong data-bind="i18n: 'Store Address'"></strong>
            <address>
                <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().street"></span>
                <br/>
                <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().city+','"></span>
                <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().zipcode"></span>
                <br/>
                <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().state+','"></span>
                <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().country"></span>
                <br/>
                <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().telephone"></span>
                <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().latitude"></span>
            </address>            
            <div class="store-map-url">
                <button type="button" class="action action-auth-toggle" data-trigger="store-description">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'More about store >>'"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- ko if: storeAddress().storemapurl -->
                <a target="_blank" class="" data-bind="attr: {href: storeAddress().storemapurl}"><span data-bind="i18n: 'View Store on Google Map >>'"></span></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <div data-bind="mageInit: {
                'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal':{
                    'type': 'popup',
                    'modalClass': 'store-dropdown',
                    'trigger': '[data-trigger=store-description]',
                    responsive: true,
                    innerScroll: true,
                    'responsive': true,
                    'buttons': []
                }}">
                <div class="store-popup-address">
                    <div class="store-popup-image">
                        <img data-bind="attr: {'src': storeAddress().image, 'alt': storeAddress().name }"  alt="" width="130" height="130"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="store-popup-name">
                        <div class="store-title" data-bind="html: storeAddress().name"></div>
                        <div class="store-email"><strong><span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().email"></span></strong></div>
                        <address>
                            <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().street"></span>
                            <br/>
                            <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().city+','"></span>
                            <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().zipcode"></span>
                            <br/>
                            <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().state+','"></span>
                            <span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().country"></span>
                            <br/>
                            <a data-bind="attr: {'href': 'tel:' + storeAddress().telephone}, text: storeAddress().telephone" href="tel:storeAddress().telephone"><span data-bind="i18n: storeAddress().telephone"></span></a>
                            <br/>
                            <a data-bind="attr: {'href': storeAddress().websiteUrl}" target="_blank"><span>Website</span></a>
                            <span> | </span>
                            <a data-bind="attr: {'href': storeAddress().facebookUrl}" target="_blank"><span>Facebook</span></a>
                            <span> | </span>
                            <a data-bind="attr: {'href': storeAddress().twitterUrl}" target="_blank"><span>Twitter</span></a>
                        </address>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="store-popup-description">
                    <div data-bind="html: storeAddress().description"></div>
                    <!-- ko if: storeAddress().storemapurl -->
                    <div class="store-map-url">
                        <a target="_blank" class="action primary" data-bind="attr: {href: storeAddress().storemapurl}"><span data-bind="i18n: 'View Store on Google Map'"></span></a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This is the html file through which i am displaying the data.

Comment: Please show your phtml file code.

Comment: @Msquare I have used the html show the data

Comment: html file is connect with which phtml file ?

Comment: @Msquare Its not connected to any phtml file. I am fetching it directly from the databse.

Answer (score 0):

**For Display Type = All Product Widget**

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" 
display_type="all_products" products_count="5" template="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget")->setDisplayType("all_products")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

**For Display Type = New Product Widget**

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" display_type="new_products" products_count="5" template="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget")->setDisplayType("new_products")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: render it on html and data is coming form the database

Answer (score 0):

You can get dynamic content like a **widget** or **block** in an `HTML template` by the below steps:
STEP 1: Create a new XML file in theme named **checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_text" template="Magento_Theme::block/custom_text.phtml" cacheable="false" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

STEP 2 : create a `PHTML` file in the below location:
**app/design/frontend/{theme_package}/{theme_name}/Magento_Theme/templates/block/custom_text.phtml**

```
<?php $dynamicText = 'Hello There'; // you can call any block widget or dynamic text here ?>
<?php // Like in your case for call widget you can use this code
      $dynamicText = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget")->setDisplayType("all_products")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.dynamicText = "<?php echo $dynamicText ?>";
</script>
```

STEP 3 : Add below code in `.html` file else any where in `.html` in **checkout**:

```
<span data-bind="html: dynamicText "></span>
```